# A Python script built upon the requests module throws a KeyError when it goes for the next page after grabbing content from the first page

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the names of different restaurants and bars from this [webpage](https://2gis.ae/dubai/search/Bars/rubricId/159) using the requests module. The script parses the content from the first page errorlessly. However, it throws a KeyError when it attempts to grab content from page two, whereas there are several pages to go.

Here is what I've been trying with:

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint

link = 'https://2gis.ae/dubai/search/Bars/rubricId/159'
url = 'https://catalog.api.2gis.ru/3.0/items'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}
params = {
    'page': 1,
    'page_size': 12,
    'rubric_id': 159,
    'fields': 'items.locale,items.flags,search_attributes,items.adm_div,items.city_alias,items.region_id,items.segment_id,items.reviews,items.point,request_type,context_rubrics,query_context,items.links,items.name_ex,items.name_back,items.org,items.group,items.external_content,items.comment,items.ads.options,items.email_for_sending.allowed,items.stat,items.description,items.geometry.centroid,items.geometry.selection,items.geometry.style,items.timezone_offset,items.context,items.address,items.is_paid,items.access,items.access_comment,items.for_trucks,items.is_incentive,items.paving_type,items.capacity,items.schedule,items.floors,dym,ad,items.rubrics,items.routes,items.reply_rate,items.purpose,items.attribute_groups,items.route_logo,items.has_goods,items.has_apartments_info,items.has_pinned_goods,items.has_realty,items.has_payments,items.is_promoted,items.delivery,items.order_with_cart,search_type,items.has_discount,items.metarubrics,broadcast,items.detailed_subtype,items.temporary_unavailable_atm_services,items.poi_category',
    'key': 'rurbbn3446',
    'locale': 'en_AE',
    'search_device_type': 'desktop',
    'search_user_hash': '7233966692562515761',
    'viewpoint1': '55.09734166196474,25.248071810295556',
    'viewpoint2': '55.421438338035266,25.16107818970444',
    'stat[sid]': '3de514cd-c705-4753-91b6-e997c2227aa7',
    'stat[user]': '1723a6dd-6008-4197-a074-c1e34e27f785',
    'shv': '2023-05-02-14',
    'r': '2843121634'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)

    while True:
        print(f"processing page ==============> {params['page']}")

        res = s.get(url,params=params)
        try:
            res.json()['result']['items']
        except KeyError:
            break

        for item in res.json()['result']['items']:
            print(item['name'])

        params['page']+=1
```

Here is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\C.L\Desktop\Python basic\python scripts\demo.py", line 35, in <module>
    res.json()['result']['items']
KeyError: 'result'
```

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: Check out the edit @Michael Butscher.

Comment: Can you `print` `res.text` for the second page? It may contain a helpful error message.

Comment: @baduker is correct.  The `r` variable in the payload changes with every page.  Trying to connect to the next page without the updated value throws a `status code` of `403.` I also noted that the site is protected with _CloudFlare_.  Have you looked at the JavaScripts files in the source to see if you can precalculate the next `r` value?

Comment: I also get the 403, but got a 200 for the first page on the first try. Some links that you ay know: [github.com/2gis/badger-api](https://github.com/2gis/badger-api/blob/master/pycd/settings.py), [docs.2gis.com](https://docs.2gis.com/en/api/search/places/examples).

Answer (score 2):

This is not a trivial page to scrape.

The second request gives this error:

```json
{
  "meta": {
    "code": 403,
    "error": {
      "message": "Authorization error (key is blocked, please contact api@2gis.ru)",
      "type": "apiKeyIsBlocked"
    },
    "api_version": "2.0.1086066",
    "issue_date": "20190201"
  }
}
```

The value for `search_user_hash` is unique and might have to do something with the value of `r`.

Take a good look at the `XHR` filter in the `Network` tab of your Dev Tools.

The value of `r` changes with subsequent requests:

```
r: 3249794585
```

which might be the **crux** of the request because if you remove it, you'll get the same error. Also, keeping the value from the previous request doesn't change anything and produces the same `403` error.

So, IMHO, you either reverse engineer how the value of `r` is populated

or

you contact `api@2gis.ru` and ask for your own API key.

Third option, use [selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/).

EDIT:

A few more words on the API:

- The map data is powered by https://dev.urbi.ae/
- This is the data you get from the API (basically, that's what you're trying to scrape) - https://dev.2gis.com/data/
- They have a free version of the API for public and open projects - https://api.2gis.ru/doc/maps/en/quickstart/
- As well as commerical and educational projects - https://dev.2gis.com/price/